# Route path="/subject/:selectedSubject" does not change subject when navigated via < Link />

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to display articles filtered by subject. When you access directly `path="/subject/:selectedSubject"` (subject/TECH) for example it works perfectly. However if you navigate through `<Link to={"/subject/TECH"} />` it will change the URL but will not load new articles.

I've tried: connecting everything with `"withRouter"`.
I know that the `<Link/>` is changing the redux state, however that is not calling `componentWillMount()` which is where `fetchArticles()` is.

So, my question is, where should I put fetchArticles in order for it to be called when  is triggered. I tried putting it inside `render()` but it keeps getting called non-stop. Or maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way.

PS: if another path gets called via `<Link/>`, like for example `path="/"`, it works as intended (loads up new articles).

at App/

```
<BrowserRouter>  
    <div>  
        <Route path="/" exact component={ArticlesList} />  
        <Route path="/subject/:selectedSubject" component={ArticlesList} />  
    </div>  
</BrowserRouter>
```

at ArticleList/

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.match.params.selectedSubject) {
      const selectedSubject = this.props.match.params.selectedSubject.toUpperCase();
      this.props.fetchArticles(selectedSubject);
    } else {
      this.props.fetchArticles();
    }
  }
```

at Link/

```
    {this.props.subjects.map(subject => {  
        return (  
            <Link to={`/subject/${subject.name}`} key={subject.name}>  
                <li>  
                    <span>{subject.name}</span>  
                </li>  
             </Link>  
        );  
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the same Component for `/` and `/subject/:selectedSubject`, he's not calling [mounting](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting) lifecycle methods, including `constructor()` and `componentDidMount()`.

You have to use [updating](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating) lifecycle method, especially [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to handle a update of your component.